# CSS3 multi column layout with jQuery horizontal scroller can't use scrollwheel between columns

Tags: jquery, html, css

I’m experiencing problems related to css3 multi column layout and a primitive sideways scrolling thing i've build in jQuery. It seems scrolling with the scrollwheel doesn’t work when the cursor has a position that is between the columns. I’ve noticed this problem in the current Chrome (28). The current firefox (22) doesn’t have this problem.

I’m currently investigating why this problem doesn’t occur with the jQuery nicescroll plugin. (Which i can’t use for other reasons)

http://jsfiddle.net/mayhem_1980/Cf3PZ/

```
<section class="multi_column_content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porta purus id nunctincidunt, a pretium magna iaculis. Nunc sem odio, pretium ac accumsan id, condimentum quis ipsum. Etiam volutpat sapien eget magna venenatis, ut malesuada felis pellentesque. Mauris nec elit lectus. Proin id viverra lacus, quis condimentum nibh. Praesent ultricies ultrices tortor id fringilla. Donec sodales imperdiet dolor, non tincidunt mi mollis nec. Duis vitae ultrices enim.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    *** Content in  this section repeats a couple of times ***
</section>

$(function() {
    var offset = 0;
    var speed = 60;

    $(window).bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e){

        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta) {
            scrollDirection = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        } else if (e.originalEvent.detail) {
            scrollDirection = -e.originalEvent.detail;
        } else {
            alert("It's broken!");
        }

        if(scrollDirection > 0) {
            offset = offset - speed;
            $("body, html").scrollLeft(offset);
        } else {
            offset = offset + speed;
            $("body, html").scrollLeft(offset);
        }
    });
});

.multi_column_content {
    -webkit-column-width: 350px;
    -moz-column-width: 350px;
    column-width: 350px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 48px;
    -moz-column-gap: 48px;
    column-gap: 48px;
    max-width: none;
    height: 40vh;
    padding: 103px 0px 24px 0px;
    text-align: justify;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should use a workaround since it is a CSS property that doesn't seem to be evenly supported.

Try adding some `padding` on those paragraphs instead of `column-gap`.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ypjF6/

For me it works!

`margins` should also work depending on what you need/want.

Comment: It's a nice and simple solution and i can see it works on jsFiddle.

However it doesn't work here. Currently investigating what other variables are in play at my local environment.

Comment: After some changes it also works locally with your solution! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It seems i can't give you a point to your answer, because as a starter here i need more reputation. However your answer is the one i accepted as the solution!

Comment: When you have the points to please upvote and/or select as correct answer. much appreciated :)